# How to update mysql table without deleting existing content

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table `mysql_table`. There is a column `Cid` for category id. 
I already uploaded many data in that table.

```
In first row, i upload ~1~2~3~ in Cid
In second row, i upload ~3~5~ in Cid
In third row , I upload ~1~ in Cid
```

Now i want to update column Cid of table mysql_table without affecting existing data. I want to update each Cid column with 15~. So that i need final reasult as

```
first row , ~1~2~3~15~
second row, ~3~5~15~
third row, ~1~15~
```

How Can I achieve this using mysql update query ?

Comment: You could use `concat`. But I think you have a serious normalization problem in you database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)** to update the existing column as

```
update mysql_table set Cid = concat(Cid,'15~');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [**CONCAT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function.

```
UPDATE `mysql_table` set Cid = concat(Cid,'15~');
```

Answer (score 0):

This untested query should do what you want.

```
update mysql_table set cid= concat(cid,'15~')
```

This append the "15~" to the end of all cid`s